# error C4716: must return a value, thrown by function that actually does return a value

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

My problem is quite simple, yet I fail to understand the cause of it and no similiar posting has turned up even after extensive research so here it is:

I have the following operator overload:

```
template <class T, size_t size>
    inline Vector<T, size> operator + (Vector<T, size> &a, Vector<T, size> &b) {
        Vector<T, size> result;
        for (auto i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            result[i] = a[i] + b[i];
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Obiously there's only a single code path, and this path also returns a value, but compiling under Visual Studio 2013, I get an error C4716, stating that the function instantiated by the compiler 'must return a value'. I get this error for all instantiations I've tried so far. I also get this error for every other operator overload in the same header, all of which are structured similarly to the snippet above.
Am I missing something obvious here?

EDIT: This is the templated vector class definition:

```
template <class T, size_t size>
    struct Vector {
        explicit Vector(T value = static_cast<T>(0)) {
            for (auto i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                _data[i] = value;
            }
        }
        explicit Vector(const Vector &other) {
            for (auto i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                _data[i] = other._data[i];
            }
        }
        explicit Vector(T values[size]) {
            for (auto i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                _data[i] = values[i];
            }
        }
        T & operator = (const Vector &other) {
            for (auto i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                _data[i] = other._data[i];
            }
            return *this;
        }

        T & operator [] (size_t index) {
            return _data[index];
        }

        T _data[size];
    };
```

Comment: `>>> masterMapOfBugs['Visual Studio Compilation Error C4716 but the function does return'] == 'Missing bracket somewhere'`

Comment: I have added the definition of the Vector class to my question.

Comment: I suppose the downvote on my question was due to the mission defintion of Vector, if not I'd be happy to hear how I can further improve my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved for my by making the copy constructor of Vector non-explicit.

To describe how I came to this conclusion, I went and specialized the operator function for Vector:

```
template <>
    inline Vector<int, 1> operator + (Vector<int, 1> &a, Vector<int, 1> &b) {
        Vector<int, 1> result;
        return result;
    }
```

Visual Studio came up with an error stating that no suitable copy constructor exists for the return value, which was resolved by removing the explicit keyword from the copy constructor. 
This would have been obvious to me if I'd properly understood how explicit copy constructors work.

Comment: This answer is unaccepted because I can only accept my own answer two days after the date of posting.

Comment: That's why you should use `std::vector` and not some home-made containers with broken semantics.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek I think it is a different kind of vector. Fixed size, with element-wise operations.

Comment: @juanchopanza It's simply an [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) named `Vector`. I am very curious why it cannot be used instead.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek I am not sure one is allowed to provide operator overloads for, say, `std::array<int, 4>`. It might also need other constructors. But at the very least it could use `std::array` internally.

Comment: Funny to see how most people assume a container class when they encounter something called 'vector'. It is actually a vector in the mathematical sense. It is templated for component type and count simply to reduce the amount of classes I have to implement myself and instead let the compiler generate the code required for each combination of component count and numeric type.